# screen.width produce different result on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript

I was working a with a site and I had know the width of the screen that's why I tried with `screen.width` but I don't know why I'm getting different result on Firefox and Chrome. Seems Firefox showing me the correct value but Chrome doesn't.

Is there is anyone who can assist me to know whats the reason?

Thanks

Comment: And whats the problem?

Comment: @Jonasw The the problem is don't you think it should show the same result?

Comment: try window.innerWidth instead. It might be helpful if you provide the snippet of code you are using too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that there is no current standard that defines what the value should be. The closest is the [CSSOM View Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#dom-screen-width), which states that:

> The width attribute must return the width of the output device, in CSS pixels.

However, that specification is a Working Draft, which means it is a work in progress and the definition stated may not be what is implemented. Indeed, the [Editor's Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#web-exposed-screen-area) gives two different definitions:

> The Web-exposed screen area is one of the following:
>
> - The area of the output device, in CSS pixels.
> - The area of the viewport, in CSS pixels.

So obviously, browser vendors are taking whichever definition they want.

For more discussion on that property, see [PPK's rant "screen.width is useless" on Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2013/11/screenwidth_is.html)